# How to Convert ed25519 Public Key to RSA x509 PEM Format?

Tags: ssh, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509, public-key

I generated key pairs using

`ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "myuser@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com"`

The resulting key:

`ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIPGT+4fswI58S6mjV+3usva03r8o8IaTX2miy+XKhdKA gke-security-tool@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

How do I convert a copy of this file to RSA x509 PEM using the Linux shell?

I could instead start with the file generated with `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`

I need the same key in both formats. What's the name of the format of the current file's format?

Comment: This isn't a programming question; it reflects ignorance of the fundamental differences between elliptic curve and prime factorization cryptography. I doubt such broad background questions are on topic for https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ but that seems your best bet.

Comment: Trying to sort through this a bit more, is your real question how to convert an SSH public key to an X.509 certificate? (Self-signed?) If so, your question has nothing to do with RSA or ed25519, and introducing those confuses the situation.

Comment: @erikson, the target system specifically asks for a "RSA_X509_PEM formatted key."   If you ignore RSA/ed25519, can. you help with the conversion?

Comment: That sounds like the target system requires a certificate, which needs a signer. Do you know if they care who signs it? My hunch is that they will accept a self-signed certificate but if you know different please clarify.

Comment: @erickson, that I don't know.  I can try it with a self-signed certificate for now.  This is for setting up a GCP service account, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about [this](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#uploading) yes it apparently wants an RSA key, not ed25519, and it wants an X.509 cert which can be self-signed *containing* the key, which is not 'converting' the key because the information in the cert is different from the information in the key, even though they confusingly and misleadingly describe it as being the public key.

The method they show is almost usable except that you want to generate the key in OpenSSH instead of OpenSSL -- although I don't know why, see below.

In OpenSSH 7.8 up, to generate RSA keypair in OpenSSH's 'old' format, which is (exactly) the same as OpenSSL's 'traditional' or 'legacy' format:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa [-b $bits] -m pem [-f private_file]
```

In lower versions omit `-m pem`; OpenSSH *already* uses 'old' format. If you already have a file generated in OpenSSH 'new' format (i.e. PEM-like labels `BEGIN/END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY`) you can convert it to 'old' format by using the change-password function:

```
ssh-keygen -p -m pem [-f private_file]
# you don't need to actually _change_ the password, you can enter 
# same value for old and new, but it re-writes the file in 'old' format
```

It's not clear to me if GCP wants specifically PKCS8 unencrypted (clear) format for the privatekey rather than OpenSSL's 'traditional' format; the *examples* all are PKCS8. If it does, use:

```
openssl pkey -in private_trad -out private_pkcs8 
# or in ancient versions (0.9.x)
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in private_trad -out private_pkcs8
```

To create the cert for the public key of this keypair, use the *private* key file (in either traditional or pkcs8), in a slight modification of the command GCP shows:

```
openssl req -x509 -new -key private_file -days 365 -out public_key.pem -subj "/CN=unused"
```

But if you want to use the same key for SSH and GCP, **it's easier to go the other direction** -- generate the keypair *and* cert with `openssl req -newkey -keyout -nodes ...`, as they show, and then use that key in OpenSSH. But you didn't ask that, so I can't give you the answer, which is that OpenSSH can already use *any* OpenSSL-format privatekey and requires only `ssh-keygen -y` to create the OpenSSH-format publickey.